# How to know how many members a certain stackexchange communitiy has?

Tags: support

How to check how many members a certain stackexchange communitiy has?

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the [site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites) and click on any of the sites you'll see the total number of questions, answers, users etc.